# How to set up and use python audit hooks

Tags: python, cpython

Python 3.8 introduces [PEP 578 -- Python Runtime Audit Hooks](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0578/) which promises to "make actions taken by the Python runtime visible to auditing tools."

This pep provides a handful of usecases which seem mostly pertinent to system admins, security professionals, and testing framework contributors. However, from what I can tell, this requires some custom options on the python implementation of choice. However, I can't find too much information online documenting how to set up these options or which options are available to implement in which implementation.

How do I get started using these hooks in cpython? Where is a complete list of all the hooks currently available (and not suggested for implementation)?

Comment: Looks like it’s the second function listed here https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

Answer (score 7):

> Where is a complete list of all the hooks currently available?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/audit_events.html

> How do I get started using these hooks in cpython?

You can start by writing your own hooks and investigate some functions.
Here's an audit to a dynamic initialization of code (code.__new event) inspired by [Dev life blog article](https://blog.jerrycodes.com/sneak-peek-python-3-8/)
Feel free to manipulate it to your own needs.

```
def audit(event, args):
    if event == 'code.__new__':
        print(f'audit: {event} with args={args}')
sys.addaudithook(audit)
```